# Integration help $\frac{1}{x^2 - x + 1}$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How do you integrate $\dfrac{1}{x^2 - x + 1}$?

I started with completing the square: $\dfrac{1}{(x-0.5)^2 + 0.75)}$.

Now I'm stuck.

Comment: do you know the derivative of $arctan$

Comment: I do, but i have trouble manipulating the equation algebraically to use arctan

Comment: Set $x-1/2=t$ and try to find the integral.

Comment: okay, using x- 1/2 = t, 

i got 4/(4t^2 +3) .. i know i can take the constant 4 out, but how do i transform the denominator to the form v^2 + 1

Comment: SOLVED! Thanks :D

Comment: $$\frac{1}{(x-0.5)^2+0.75}=\frac{1}{0.75}\cdot \frac{1}{\left(\frac{x-0.5}{\sqrt{0.75}}\right)^2+1}$$

Let $u=\frac{x-0.5}{\sqrt{0.75}}$. Then $\sqrt{0.75}\, du=dx$. $$\int \frac{dx}{\left(\frac{x-0.5}{\sqrt{0.75}}\right)^2+1}=\sqrt{0.75}\int \frac{1}{u^2+1}\, du$$

Comment: @user236182 Er... I think in this case, it might be clearer to use the fractional values for the fractions. It also looks better too.

Answer (score 1):

After shifting the variable, you have obtained

$$\int\frac{du}{u^2+\dfrac34},$$ which reminds of the $\arctan$ function, such that

$$\int\frac{dt}{t^2+1}=\arctan t+C.$$

To reduce to this form, you use a scaling of the variable in such a way that the denominator $u^2+\dfrac34$ becomes $\dfrac34t^2+\dfrac34$. This is achieved by setting

$$u=\dfrac{\sqrt3}2t.$$

The rest is yours.

Answer (score 1):

The integral can be solved with a series of substitutions. Starting off where you left off, we have$$\begin{align*}\int\frac {dx}{\left(x-\tfrac 12\right)^2+\tfrac 34} & =\int\frac {du}{u^2+\tfrac 34}\\ & =\frac 43\int\frac {du}{1+\tfrac {4u^2}3}\\ & =\frac 2{\sqrt3}\int\frac {ds}{1+s^2}\\ & =\frac 2{\sqrt3}\arctan s\end{align*}$$